# Angular Velocity of Semicircle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

In a 2-Dimensional world, a semicircle with center O, mass M and radius r is placed on the ground, with C as the point of contact. A small beetle of mass $m$ is placed at C which starts walking towards B with velocity $v$ which causes the ball to rotate. What is the angular velocity of the semicircle with respect to time?

Please do suggest edits if needed
[image: The Image]

Comment: Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate angular velocity by taking origin ofyour frame on semicircle centre.unknowns as torque and friction force can be calcuted by balancing forces and writing torque equations knowing mass of beetle and semicircle.